# I am having error in Asterisk

Tags: linux, networking, openwrt, voip, asterisk

I am working with Asterisk 13 on OpenWRT(Linux distro) and having following error.

> -- SIP/sipphone-00000000 is making progress passing it to DAHDI/1-1 [Aug  7 22:40:44] ERROR[13139][C-00000000]: netsock2.c:305
>   ast_sockaddr_resolve: getaddrinfo("gw0-1.new-york-1.pstn.jnctn.net",
>   "(null)", ...): Name or service not known [Aug  7 22:40:44]
>   WARNING[13139][C-00000000]: chan_sip.c:16589
>   __set_address_from_contact: Invalid host name in Contact: (can't resolve in DNS) : 'gw0-1.new-york-1.pstn.jnctn.net'

Can somebody tell me the solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your box is trying to connect to a SIP-to-PSTN gateway named "gw0-1.new-york-1.pstn.jnctn.net", but that host doesn't have a DNS record (it probably no longer exists). Check your SIP configuration. It looks like maybe that gateway address came from the contact info of someone you were trying to call, so maybe check whether you have the right SIP address for the person you were trying to call.